# Where is better to place global variables at laravel?

Tags: laravel, global-variables

I have to use global variables in some controllers and views, where is better to place them? At .env file or config/ files for example config/app.php?
Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth do you think you have to use global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

global variable is a synonym for bad practice , i think you can't make it better

i also think that this question is opinion based.

anyway

why you dont do this

you can create a new controller  lets say **BaseController**

```
BaseController extends Controller {

    protected $hodor;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $hodor = 'HOLD THE FREAKIN DOOR';
    }

}
```

Then in your other controllers you can do this

```
MyOtherController extends BaseController {

    public function hodor()
    {
        echo "today: $this->hodor";
    }

}
```

But as i said Global variables are considered as bad practices so **i think** You should use sessions

i think you can use a **config file** or **.env**

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are bad for sure. But using custom config is not the same as using global variables.

Create custom config file and put it under `config` directory. Then you'll be able to use config's variables from any part of your app:

```
$variable = config('configname.variablename');
```

Comment: i already mentioned that , but i think it drpends on what he wants exactly, it would be better if he shares some code

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja, your answer is telling not to use it at all and use sessions instead. Then you've mentioned `.env` and configs. My answer is 'use configs' and I want to tell that using config is not a bad practice (Laravel and many great packages use it). I also give an example of using it.

Comment: actualy, i can't find the part 'done use them' i only said its a bad practice ,but then i said 'You can use .env or cfg' anyway dont missunderstand me! **i just thought** its **almost** the same answer + some exemple code of how to use a cfg file

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja, I think my answer is really different from yours (another meaning + code example), I'm not that kind of guy who posts same/similar answers. I'm sorry if it offended you.